# Why does TypeScript, with the strictFunctionTypes option enabled, throws a type assignment error when I pass more than 8 rxjs operators?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

When TypeScript compiles code that has an Observable with more than 9 pipe operators, it throws a type assignment error. This only happens with the `strictFunctionTypes` option enabled.

```
  Argument of type '(...) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: {}) => void'.
Types of parameters '...' and 'value' are incompatible.
  Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type '...': ...
```

Here's the code:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

interface User {
  id: number,
  name: string
}

/*
  Argument of type '(user: User) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: {}) => void'.
    Types of parameters 'user' and 'value' are incompatible.
      Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'User': id, name
*/
of(true).pipe(
  tap(() => console.log('tap')),
  tap(() => console.log('tap')),
  tap(() => console.log('tap')),
  tap(() => console.log('tap')),
  tap(() => console.log('tap')),
  tap(() => console.log('tap')),
  tap(() => console.log('tap')),
  tap(() => console.log('tap')),
  tap(() => console.log('tap')),
  tap(() => console.log('tap')),
  tap(() => console.log('tap')),
  tap(() => console.log('tap')),
  tap(() => console.log('tap')),
  switchMap(() => of({ id: 0, name: 'John' } as User))
).subscribe((user: User) => console.log(user));
```

Live code example: https://repl.it/repls/RegalTameTrace#index.ts

Moreover, if you pass less than 10 operators, then the error will not occur:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

interface User {
  id: number,
  name: string
}

// works
of(true).pipe(
  tap(() => console.log('tap')),
  tap(() => console.log('tap')),
  tap(() => console.log('tap')),
  tap(() => console.log('tap')),
  tap(() => console.log('tap')),
  tap(() => console.log('tap')),
  tap(() => console.log('tap')),
  tap(() => console.log('tap')),
  switchMap(() => of({ id: 0, name: 'John' } as User))
).subscribe((user: User) => console.log(user));
```

Live code example: https://repl.it/repls/InfiniteDarkturquoiseApplicationframework#index.ts

This happens not only with the `tap` operator, but with any other:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

interface User {
  id: number,
  name: string
}

/*
  Argument of type '(user: User) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: {}) => void'.
    Types of parameters 'user' and 'value' are incompatible.
      Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'User': id, name
*/
of(true).pipe(
  switchMap(() => of('')),
  switchMap(() => of('')),
  switchMap(() => of('')),
  switchMap(() => of('')),
  switchMap(() => of('')),
  switchMap(() => of('')),
  switchMap(() => of('')),
  switchMap(() => of('')),
  switchMap(() => of('')),
  switchMap(() => of({ id: 0, name: 'John' } as User))
).subscribe((user: User) => console.log(user));

// works
of(true).pipe(
  switchMap(() => of('')),
  switchMap(() => of('')),
  switchMap(() => of('')),
  switchMap(() => of('')),
  switchMap(() => of('')),
  switchMap(() => of('')),
  switchMap(() => of('')),
  switchMap(() => of('')),
  switchMap(() => of({ id: 0, name: 'John' } as User))
).subscribe((user: User) => console.log(user));
```

Live code examples:
https://repl.it/repls/SpectacularPrivateAngle#index.ts
https://repl.it/repls/GrippingStrictMode#index.ts

Why is this happening? This looks contradictory.

tsconf.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "types": ["node"],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TS compiler throws an error because `pipe` function according to source [code](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/util/pipe.ts) can guarantee proper types for up to 10 arguments.

If you use more arguments, you should disable TS checks `// @ts-ignore`

Here is the code:

```js
export function pipe<T>(): UnaryFunction<T, T>;
export function pipe<T, A>(fn1: UnaryFunction<T, A>): UnaryFunction<T, A>;
export function pipe<T, A, B>(fn1: UnaryFunction<T, A>, fn2: UnaryFunction<A, B>): UnaryFunction<T, B>;
export function pipe<T, A, B, C>(fn1: UnaryFunction<T, A>, fn2: UnaryFunction<A, B>, fn3: UnaryFunction<B, C>): UnaryFunction<T, C>;
export function pipe<T, A, B, C, D>(fn1: UnaryFunction<T, A>, fn2: UnaryFunction<A, B>, fn3: UnaryFunction<B, C>, fn4: UnaryFunction<C, D>): UnaryFunction<T, D>;
export function pipe<T, A, B, C, D, E>(fn1: UnaryFunction<T, A>, fn2: UnaryFunction<A, B>, fn3: UnaryFunction<B, C>, fn4: UnaryFunction<C, D>, fn5: UnaryFunction<D, E>): UnaryFunction<T, E>;
export function pipe<T, A, B, C, D, E, F>(fn1: UnaryFunction<T, A>, fn2: UnaryFunction<A, B>, fn3: UnaryFunction<B, C>, fn4: UnaryFunction<C, D>, fn5: UnaryFunction<D, E>, fn6: UnaryFunction<E, F>): UnaryFunction<T, F>;
export function pipe<T, A, B, C, D, E, F, G>(fn1: UnaryFunction<T, A>, fn2: UnaryFunction<A, B>, fn3: UnaryFunction<B, C>, fn4: UnaryFunction<C, D>, fn5: UnaryFunction<D, E>, fn6: UnaryFunction<E, F>, fn7: UnaryFunction<F, G>): UnaryFunction<T, G>;
export function pipe<T, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H>(fn1: UnaryFunction<T, A>, fn2: UnaryFunction<A, B>, fn3: UnaryFunction<B, C>, fn4: UnaryFunction<C, D>, fn5: UnaryFunction<D, E>, fn6: UnaryFunction<E, F>, fn7: UnaryFunction<F, G>, fn8: UnaryFunction<G, H>): UnaryFunction<T, H>;
export function pipe<T, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I>(fn1: UnaryFunction<T, A>, fn2: UnaryFunction<A, B>, fn3: UnaryFunction<B, C>, fn4: UnaryFunction<C, D>, fn5: UnaryFunction<D, E>, fn6: UnaryFunction<E, F>, fn7: UnaryFunction<F, G>, fn8: UnaryFunction<G, H>, fn9: UnaryFunction<H, I>): UnaryFunction<T, I>;
export function pipe<T, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I>(fn1: UnaryFunction<T, A>, fn2: UnaryFunction<A, B>, fn3: UnaryFunction<B, C>, fn4: UnaryFunction<C, D>, fn5: UnaryFunction<D, E>, fn6: UnaryFunction<E, F>, fn7: UnaryFunction<F, G>, fn8: UnaryFunction<G, H>, fn9: UnaryFunction<H, I>, ...fns: UnaryFunction<any, any>[]): UnaryFunction<T, {}>;
```

Comment: Instead of disabling TS and throwing its checks out the window it'd be easier and better to just use multiple calls to pipe().

Comment: @IngoBürk not sure what is best trade-off. I think that adding comment before `// @ts-ignore` about why it is being put is more convenient and readable than multiple `pipe(...).pipe(...)` chain.

Comment: If you don't care about types and would rather disable them, why bother using TS?

Comment: @IngoBürk strict types let you to do less mistakes in all other code. I also came to conclusion that multiple `pipe` chain looks neat, if you write them on a new line, after an Observable, like so: https://repl.it/repls/ViciousUnimportantPorts#script.js